# Remove File After Time in PHP

Tags: php, exe

I have a php script that provides a link to a temporary file that is created with the script. I want the person to be able to download the file, but I don't want the file to stay on the server for a long time. I would like to remove the file say maybe after 2 minutes. How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove it right after the download. output the content of the file, then close it and `unlink` it.

**Edit**: example

```
$fo = fopen($f, 'rb') ;
    $content = fread($fo, filesize($f)) ;
    fclose($fo) ;
}
// Stream the file to the client 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($archive)); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"myfile.exe\""); 
echo $archive;
unlink($f);
```

Comment: This sounds great, but how can I output the content of the file? I meant to say that the file that is to be downloaded is actually an executable (.exe) file that was the result of a C++ compilation. How can I give the user a exe file download?

Comment: Send the appropriate header `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` before writing to the buffer.

Comment: QAH, what streetpc is saying is don't provide a link to the file. Instead your original script should produce the file and output it to the user with the above code.  Or you can provide a link to a script such as the one above that outputs and removes the file.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a cron job to to run your cleaning script every few minutes.  You could use the [filemtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) function to see when a file was created, and delete it if the file is considered "old enough".